# How do I filter an SQL query that joins two tables, where an item is associated with too many items it is joined to?

Tags: sql

There are two tables: A, with rows (row_id, column1, ...) and B, with rows (column2, ...).

```
Select * from A
   join B on A.column1 = B.column2
```

There can be 1 or more records in table B having column2 = A.column1. Every record in B has a matching record in A, but not every record in A has records in B.

What is an efficient query to get the `row_id` in table A, that has more than 100 records in table B associated with it?

Comment: Absolutely - clear titles make the question easier to find for those who can answer them, and better for future users looking for an answer to the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT `row_id`
FROM `A`
JOIN `B` ON (`B`.`column2` = `A`.`column1`)
GROUP BY `A`.`row_id`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 100
```

Answer (score 3):

This will give you all the columns from table A:

```
select A.*
from A
inner join (
    select column2
    from B
    group by column2
    having count(*) > 100
) BC on A.column1 = BC.column2
```

If you just need the ID, you can do this:

```
select column2
from B
group by column2
having count(*) > 100
```